# Branchless way to represent a "ping-pong" value?

Tags: c++, function, math, c++11, numbers

I need a changing value that can be manually *stepped* with `step()` that goes back and forth a `min` and a `max`, moving by `speed` every `step()`.

This is my current code:

```
template<typename T> struct PingPongValue {
        T value, min, max, speed, dir{1};

        PingPongValue(T mMin, T mMax, T mSpeed) 
           : value(mMin), min(mMin), max(mMax), speed(mSpeed) { }

        void step()
        {
            value += speed * dir;
                 if(value > max) { value = max; dir = -1; }
            else if(value < min) { value = min; dir = +1; }
        }
};
```

Example:

```
PingPongValue v{0, 5, 1};
v.step(); // v.value == 1
v.step(); // v.value == 2
v.step(); // v.value == 3
v.step(); // v.value == 4
v.step(); // v.value == 5
v.step(); // v.value == 4
v.step(); // v.value == 3
v.step(); // v.value == 2
// etc...
```

I suppose there's a mathematical way to represent this as a branchless function, but I cannot figure it out. I tried using modulo but I still need a `dir` variable to change step direction.

Comment: ((x / 5) * 2 - 1) is -1 or 1 if x is in {0,1,2,3,4} or {5,6,7,8,9}, respectively.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Yup. I wish there is a generic, short and sweet solution like this.

Comment: Oh, it fails for -1, though. I can fix that, but it gets a bit more convoluted. -(((x+5)/5) % 2 * 2 - 1) does it, but now one wonders if the branch is more or less costly. (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-%28%28floor%28%28%28x%2B5%29%2F5%29%29+mod+2%29+*+2+-+1%29)

Comment: Arghh, broken link. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-%28%28floor%28%28%28x%2B5%29%2F5%29%29+mod+2%29+%2A+2+-+1%29. Anyway, the original looks highly branch-predictable to me...

Comment: Is arithmetic on T exact? In particular, does `speed` exactly divide `max-min` ?

Comment: Your function is discontinuous in the middle. Can't be done "mathematically".
You have to divide by 0 or branch. (floor isn't branchless)
Can be done with a cache array you walk as suggested by Paul Evans.

Comment: Question is what is the purpose for doing this? A slew of answers can be given but without a reason, there is no point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with an array, something like this (WARNING: probably has off-by-one errors galore!):

```
int total_steps = 2*(max - min + 1)/speed; // this may be wrong -- have to double check
T steps[total_steps];
for(int i = 0; i < max - min; ++i)
    steps[total_steps - i] = steps[i] = min + i*speed;
```

Then you can use modulo `total_steps` to step through the array forever.

Comment: Yes there are off by one errors but trying to solve them without testing would be too dangerous ;) Testing is a *must* in this case but  of course this is up to the OP.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good solution in my use case. If I need floating point precision I'll just use the branched version, as, according to the other answers, it's easily predictable by the CPU.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo - this should work for floating point steps as well.  It's basically just a mapping of `0`...`total_steps - 1` to `min`..`max`..`min` by increments (then decrements) of `speed` - these `min`, `max` and `speed` values can be `double`'s.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a fan of "branchless" algorithms, as many times they're just used "because branching is slow", and in that case, IMO it's the optimizer's job to find a faster way.

Nevertheless, you could use comparisons, as bools yield either `0` or `1` when converted to an integral type. Whether that's branchless depends on the architecture AFAIK.

```
value += speed*dir;                           // allowing over-/underflow
value += (min-value)*(value<min) + (max-value)*(value>max);  // clamp
dir   += 2* ((value==min) - (value==max));    // set dir
```

SSCCE:

```
template<typename T> struct PingPongValue {
        T value, min, max, speed, dir{1};

        PingPongValue(T mMin, T mMax, T mSpeed) 
           : value(mMin), min(mMin), max(mMax), speed(mSpeed) { }

        void step()
        {
            // allowing over-/underflow
            value += speed*dir;

            // clamp
            value += (min-value)*(value<min) + (max-value)*(value>max);

            // set dir
            dir   += 2* ((value==min) - (value==max));
        }
};


#include <iostream>

template<class T>
void step(PingPongValue<T>& v)
{
    v.step();
    std::cout << "stepped to: " << v.value << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    PingPongValue<int> p{-3, 6, 2};
    std::cout << "initial: " << p.value << std::endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        step(p);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
initial: -3
stepped to: -1
stepped to: 1
stepped to: 3
stepped to: 5
stepped to: 6
stepped to: 4
stepped to: 2
stepped to: 0
stepped to: -2
stepped to: -3
```

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, you have to employ some periodic function like sin(x) and normalize it to your desired scale. For example, Triangle wave: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave

Another approach (maybe, more preferred for simple cases) is to use an array of pre-calculated results and iterate through them (and handle index overflow with help of mod function).

Answer (score 1):

```
        int min = 2;
        int max = 7;
        int step = 1;

        int d = max - min;
        int n = d;

        for( int i = 0; min<1000; ++i)
        {
            int x = min + abs(d - n); // the result
            n = (n + step) % (2 * d); // the step
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my idea in pseudocode, no guarantees though :)
This should emulate what your example does, but not what your code does. That is, it should create a series 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, ... whereas your code would create 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, ...

The comments illustrate the behaviour with min=1, max=5, speed=1

```
size = max-min; // 4
internalValue = (internalValue + speed) % (size*2); // 0, 1, ..., 7, 0, 1, ...
reverse = internalValue / size; // 0 for internalValue in [0, 3], 1 for [4, 7]
value = min + internalValue - 2*reverse*(internalValue - size);
```

internalValue is the only actual state variable here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a [branchless `abs`-function](http://www.strchr.com/optimized_abs_function), you can use this:

```
template<typename T> struct PingPongValue {
    T value, inner, min, max, speed;

    PingPongValue(T mMin, T mMax, T mSpeed) 
       : value(mMin), inner(0), min(mMin), max(mMax), speed(mSpeed) { }

    void step()
    {
        inner = (inner + speed) % ((mMax - mMin) * 2);
        value = mMax - abs(inner - mMax + 1) + mMin - 1;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you are trying to ping-pong between 6 and 11:

You are trying to repeat the following sequence:

```
f4(i) = 6 7 8 9 10 11 10 9 8 7
```

Suppose it's formed by adding 6 to the values of another sequence :

```
f3(i) = 0 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1
```

Suppose it's formed by taking the absolute value of another sequence.

```
f2(i) = 0 1 2 3 4 5 -4 -3 -2 -1
```

Suppose now that you got these numbers by substracting 4 from the values of another sequence.

```
f1(i) = 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3
```

Then you have:

```
f1(i) = (i + 4) % 10;
f2(i) = f1(i) - 4;
f3(i) = abs(f2(i));
f4(i) = f3(i) + 6
```

Replace:

```
min = 6
2*(max - min) = 10
max - min - 1 = 4
```

You get:

```
f1(i) = (i + max - min - 1) % 2*(max - min);
f2(i) = f1(i) - (max - min - 1);
f3(i) = abs(f2(i));
f4(i) = f3(i) + min;
```